# What does the abbreviation EOIR stand for?

Tags: usa, immigration

I see this line on the Form I-765 instructions

> If you have filed your Form I-485 with EOIR, you must submit proof that you are currently in immigration proceedings, that you have filed Form I-485 with the immigration court, and that the Form I-485 remains pending, before filing Form I-765 with USCIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EIOR is the [Executive Office for Immigration Review](https://www.justice.gov/eoir). This is where you would appeal a deportation.

Comment: Removal proceedings are held in immigration courts. Immigration court decisions can be appealed to the Board of Immigration Appeals (BIA). Both immigration courts and the BIA are part of the EOIR.